# How to define relationships programmatically in Entity Framework 4.1's Code-First Fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm playing around with the new EF4.1 unicorn love.

I'm trying to understand the different ways I can use **code-first** to **programatically** define my relationships between a few simple POCO's.

How can I define the following =>

1. 1 `Team` has 0-many `User`s. (and a `User` is in 1 `Team`)
2. 1 `User` has 0-or-1 `Foo`'s (but a `Foo` has no property going back to a `User`)
3. 1 `User` has 1 `UserStuff`

Answer (score 11):

Here you have examples you are looking for:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public UserStuff UserStuff { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class UserStuff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserStuff> UserStuff { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.Team)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.Foo)
            .WithRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.UserStuff)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.Foo)
            .WithRequired();` AND `modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.Foo)` ?
Both would allow 0-or-1 Foo's in User or?

Answer (score 5):

Lets introduce a few specific classes to illustrate the solutions:

```
public class Account
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a helper class to make the mapping classes a bit less verbose:

```
internal abstract class AbstractMappingProvider<T> : IMappingProvider where T : class
{
    public EntityTypeConfiguration<T> Map { get; private set; }

    public virtual void DefineModel( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        Map = modelBuilder.Entity<T>();

        Map.ToTable( typeof(T).Name );
    }
}
```

Now for the mappings. Lets do the "1:1" mapping first. In my example user and account are 1:1 related and share the same primary key (only one of them will be an identity column, which in this case is the Account.ID).

```
internal class UserMapping : AbstractMappingProvider<User>
{
    public override void DefineModel( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.DefineModel( modelBuilder );
        Map.HasRequired( e => e.Account ).WithRequiredDependent( r => r.User ).WillCascadeOnDelete( true );
    }
}

internal class AccountMapping : AbstractMappingProvider<Account>
{
    public override void DefineModel( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.DefineModel( modelBuilder );
        Map.HasRequired( e => e.User ).WithRequiredPrincipal( r => r.Account ).WillCascadeOnDelete( true );
    }
}
```

In the following mappings we specify that a team has (0..n) users, while a single user is in exactly one team (required). We also specify that a team can have a company, but company does not expose a list of teams.

```
internal class TeamMapping : AbstractMappingProvider<Team>
{
    public override void DefineModel( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.DefineModel( modelBuilder );
        Map.HasOptional( e => e.Company ).WithMany().HasForeignKey( e => e.CompanyID );
        Map.HasMany( e => e.Users ).WithRequired( r => r.Team );
    }
}   

internal class CompanyMapping : AbstractMappingProvider<Company>
{
    public override void DefineModel( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.DefineModel( modelBuilder );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you do with EntityTypeConfiguration ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The DbModelBuilder instance passed to DefineModel exposes a property of this type, which I expose on AbstractMappingProvider as the Map property. This allows the individual derived mapping classes to simply use Map. to access the EntityTypeConfiguration instance used to define the mappings.